# Simplify boolean algebra : (w'x+yz')((xz+w)(y+xz'))'

Tags: boolean-algebra

(w'x+yz')((xz+w)(y+xz'))'
I gotten the answer w'xy'z+wyz'
however the answer sheet was w'xz' +w'xy'z+w'yz'
can anyone confirm?

Comment: please show your steps, so we can confirm them

Answer (score 0):

Or consult WolframAlpha, but that only adds even more different solutions
(w'xy' + w'yz'):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ANF+%28%28~w+%26%26+x%29+%7C%7C+%28y+%26%26+~z%29%29+%26%26+~%28%28%28x+%26%26+z%29%7C%7Cw%29+%26%26+%28y%7C%7C%28x+%26%26+~z%29%29%29